# How to use @Autowired inside a ConstraintValidator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to use dependency injection in a `ConstraintValidator` defined nested to a `@interface`?

I have created custom annotation which needs to validate some data.

`CodebookValidator` is just a normal class: it isn't annotated with `@Service`, `@Component`... However DI doesn't work even when I annotate it with `@Service`...

Any idea on how can I use `@Autowired` inside a `ConstraintValidator`? Here's snippet of code:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CodebookValue.CodebookValidator.class)
public @interface CodebookValue {

    Codebook value();

    String message() default "Not valid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class CodebookValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CodebookValue, String> {

        @Autowired
        private CodebookService codebookService; // this won't work it's null at runtime

        private Codebook codebook;

        @Override
        public void initialize(CodebookValue constraintAnnotation) {
            codebook = constraintAnnotation.value();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
            String translate = codebookService.translate(value, codebook, codebook.getSourceSystem());
            return StringUtils.isEmpty(translate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide your own [`Validator`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Validator.html) bean with Spring autowiring capabilities:

```java
@Bean
public Validator validator(final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
            .configure()
            .constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(beanFactory))
            .buildValidatorFactory();

    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}
```